# How to make block integrated with figure

Tags: beamer, block

I am making a poster in a beamer using the Gemini style, and I have three figures that I want to display in a 2x2 pattern. For the fourth display (bottom-right) I want to be a block with text in it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]%
 \centering
 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image-a}\label{fig:a}}%
 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image-b}\label{fig:b}}\\
 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image-c}\label{fig:c}}%
 \begin{block}
    \lipsum
\end{block}
 \caption{Some caption}%
 \label{some-label}%
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, if the following suggestion work for you:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=.4\linewidth} % <---
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}\label{fig:a}}%
    \hfil
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}\label{fig:b}}\\
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-c}\label{fig:c}}%
    \hfil
 \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\linewidth} % <---
    \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{minipage}
 \caption{Some caption}%
 \label{some-label}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or like this:

[image]

where in minipage is inserted a `block`:

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \begin{block}{Block title}\small
        \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \end{block}
\end{minipage}
```